# Cannot access Authorized content in .NET Core using JWT authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, postman

I developed a sample app where I use JWT authentication to access the private content.

After getting a token in Postman, I am able to pass it to the private controller action also via Postman and it works all well.

But when I try to use `SignInManager` to access, it won't work.  `User.Identity.Name` and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` are always nulls

Here's my startup code

```
public class Startup
{
    private AppModule appModule;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        appModule = new AppModule();
        AppModule.Configuration = Configuration; //setting up of static variable

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        string connectionSring = null;
        if (true) //(env.IsDevelopment())
            connectionSring = appModule.GetConnectionString(EuConstants.LOCAL_CONNECTION_NAME);
        else
            connectionSring = appModule.GetConnectionString(EuConstants.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME);



        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionSring);
        });



        /* tell the framework to use our cusom user and role classes */
        services.AddIdentity<Gn_User, Gn_Role>(options =>

        {
            options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o => {
            o.LoginPath = "/portal/login";
        });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddAuthentication(option => {
            option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Site"],
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Site"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:SigningKey"]))
            };
        });


        services.AddScoped<AppModule>(sp => appModule
        );

        services.AddMvc(
            options =>
            {
                // make sure that all attributes by default required authentication
               // options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()));
            }
            ).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();



        // tell the application to use the authentication
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Portal}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

and here's the authentication method to generate the token

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] Gn_User model)
    {
        string password = "yaser@1234";
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
        {
            var claim = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName)
            };
            var signinKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
              Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AppModule.Configuration["Jwt:SigningKey"]));

            int expiryInMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(AppModule.Configuration["Jwt:ExpiryInMinutes"]);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
              issuer: AppModule.Configuration["Jwt:Site"],
              audience: AppModule.Configuration["Jwt:Site"],
              expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expiryInMinutes),
              signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signinKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

            return Ok(
              new
              {
                  token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                  expiration = token.ValidTo
              });
        }
        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `SignInManager to access`? How did you request the security content without postman?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add your claims to your JWT.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] Gn_User model)
{
    string password = "yaser@1234";
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
    if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
    {
        var claim = new[] {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName)
        };
        var signinKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
          Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AppModule.Configuration["Jwt:SigningKey"]));

        int expiryInMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(AppModule.Configuration["Jwt:ExpiryInMinutes"]);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
          issuer: AppModule.Configuration["Jwt:Site"],
          audience: AppModule.Configuration["Jwt:Site"],
          /////////////////////////////////
          claims : claim,// Dont Forget To Add Claims To Your JWT
          /////////////////////////////////
          expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expiryInMinutes),
          signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signinKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );

        return Ok(
          new
          {
              token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
              expiration = token.ValidTo
          });
    }
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

Comment: it's still not working by adding the missing claims, but I don't know if there's a mismatch between the login parameters and those identified in startup.cs.

of course it's still working by calling it from Postman and provide the header with the authentication token

Answer (score 0):

I worked for me by adding the following code to register the identity.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

instead of passing the parameters as options

```
services.AddAuthentication(op => {
      op.defaultSchema...... = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
})
```